# JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set on Swift async function

Tags: swift, google-cloud-functions

I'm playing around with Swift and Firebase cloud functions and can't get this simple call to work.

index.js:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const original = req.query.text;
  const writeResult = await admin.firestore().collection('messages').add({original: original});
  
  res.json({result: `Message with ID: ${writeResult.id} added.`});
});
```

SwiftUI button:

```
Button {
    
    let testVM: TestViewModel = TestViewModel()
                    
    Task.init {
        try await testVM.checkTestFunc(data: "heyMama")
    }
                    
} label: {
    HStack {
        Image(systemName: "heart")
        Text("Click me")
        Spacer()
        Image(systemName: "arrow.up.forward.app")
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
lazy var functions = Functions.functions()

func checkTestFunc(data: String) async throws -> Bool {

    do {

        let result = try await functions.httpsCallable("http://localhost:5001/myProjectID/us-central1/addMessage").call(["text": data])

        print("result: \(result)")

    } catch {
        print("error: \(error)")
    }

    return false

}
```

Error message:

> error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set. around line 2, column 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set. around line 2, column 0., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=1}

Comment: I noticed you use`http`, you should use `https`, or add the appropriate `NSAppTransportSecurity` in your `Info.plist`
So you are probably getting some message from the server, but it is not the results you expect to decode.

Comment: Adding "s" didn't work. I'm using the exact address that I get from the console after deploying the function

Comment: did you enable your server for `HTTPS` ?

Comment: yes. And just to make it clear - When I go to this address ( http://localhost:5001/myProjectID/us-central1/addMessage?text=heyMama ) from my browser, it'll initiate the functions properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there are two types of cloud functions that can receive my request and each one will get it in a different way so there are two ways to approach this issue.

The first one is to change the way I send the parameter. So instead of using an array, I'll send it as part of the function name like this:

```
let result = try await functions.httpsCallable("addMessage?text=\(data)").call()
```

The second way is to use an 'onCall' method on the cloud function like this which will get the array (i prefer this solution as it feels more secured):

```
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

  const original = data.text;

  ...
  
  return {...};
});
```